# extract canvas from vnc viewer

Tags: html, canvas, copy, vnc

Has anyone experienced working or even building/creating vnc canvas viewer? I posted similar question a while ago, but there was no answer. :(

What I (really) need is to ether extract canvas from (e.g. ThinVNC) viewer that displays virtual machine or try to build one. I need to embed virtual machine as part of the Web page.

For example,

I can use iFrame, but I can't clone canvas that displays virtual machine from that iFrame.
I've tried with vnc.js, but I have difficulties with sockets.io.
OnlineVNC is good, but it's Flash-based (I used FlashVNC earlier) and my new app doesn't support Flash anymore.

Any advice on how to extract/copy/clone vnc canvas will be valuable!

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've done this. The problem is that VNC runs over raw TCP sockets, which aren't available in standard JavaScript - all you have are WebSockets which impose an extra layer over the TCP socket that makes it incompatible with standard VNC servers.

Your options are:

- Restrict yourself to JavaScript environments which offer real TCP sockets, e.g. emulated using Flash.
- Use a VNC server which natively supports WebSockets. Some of them may have undocumented options to do this...
- Use a WebSockets-to-TCP gateway. This is what they did with `vnc.js`.

Once you've figured out how to make the sockets side of it work, you may have more success with `vnc.js` or you can write your own. (I used [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) to port a C/C++ VNC viewer SDK codebase to JavaScript, then wrote a canvas layer on top. Unfortunately it's closed source so I can't share it with you, but it's probably easier to start with `vnc.js` anyway.